# How to identify code memory model through which an object file is generated?

Tags: gcc, ld, memory-model, gnu-toolchain

I have a relocatable object file. I want to verify whether it was build with medium/large/small memory code model (-mcmodel g++ option.).
Is there a way to get that information through objdump/readelf or any other GNU toolchain utility?

Also, I have an encrypted binary file which is being compiled as -

```
ld  -r -b binary -o <relocatable_object_file> <encrypted_binary_file>
```

How can I compile this file with medium code memory model (since it is a gcc option and not ld)?

Comment: (1) AFAIK there is no such tool. Different code models are just code generation options. When you change the model, only the actual machine instructions change, the rest of the object stays the same. So you would have to analyze the instructions. (2) Since it is a gcc option and not ld, you need to use gcc and not ld, and feed it the source code together with the rest of the options.